# Generic sum of two numeric expressions

Tags: scala

I am writing a little toy language built on top of expressions. Here is some code to get the idea:

```
trait Expression[+T] {
  def eval: T
}

case class Literal[+T](value: T) extends Expression[T] {
  def eval = value
}
```

The parser builds a tree of expressions which are then evaluated by calling the `eval` method. Now I want to add a Sum expression that represents the sum of two other expressions:

```
case class Sum[+T: Numeric](left: Expression[T], right: Expression[T]) {
  def eval = implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(left.eval, right.eval)
}
```

This works fine if the left and right expression have the same type (as specified by the constructor). But naturally I would like it to work in the following case as well:
`Sum(Literal(1.1), Literal(1))`

This does not work because the compiler does not find an implicit argument of type `Numeric[AnyVal]`, which makes sense.

I came up with the following code, using type bounds, to try to fix the issue:

```
case class Sum2[+T: Numeric, L <% T, R <% T](left: Expression[L], right: Expression[R]) extends Expression[T] {
  def eval = implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(left.eval, right.eval)
}
```

Now the compiler complains that `left.eval` and `right.eval` are not of type `T`. Casting to `T` using `asInstanceOf[T]` generates more compiler errors because of ambiguous implicit arguments.

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was pointed in the comments, the fact that there is safe conversion from `Int` to `Double` for your operation is not enough for the compiler to be able prove that this conversion is valid in all relevant contexts. I'm not aware of any simpler way to achieve what you want than this code ([see also online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YBG54S1NRYWRiRk6ab4IXQ)):

```
trait Expression[+T] {
  def eval: T
}

trait TypeConverter[S, T] {
  def convert(value: S): T
}

trait TypeConverterLowPriority {
  implicit def compose[A, B, C](implicit aToB: TypeConverter[A, B], bToC: TypeConverter[B, C]): TypeConverter[A, C] = new TypeConverter.TypeConverterImpl(a => bToC.convert(aToB.convert(a)))
}

object TypeConverter extends TypeConverterLowPriority {

  class TypeConverterImpl[S, T](f: S => T) extends TypeConverter[S, T] {
    override def convert(value: S): T = f(value)
  }

  def sameType[T]: TypeConverter[T, T] = new TypeConverterImpl(identity)


  implicit val intToDouble: TypeConverter[Int, Double] = new TypeConverterImpl(_.toDouble)
  implicit val shortToInt: TypeConverter[Short, Int] = new TypeConverterImpl(_.toInt)
  // add more "primitive" type conversions here

}

case class Literal[+T](value: T) extends Expression[T] {
  def eval = value
}


trait BinaryOpImpl[A, B, R] {
  protected val numericR: Numeric[R]
  protected val aToR: TypeConverter[A, R]
  protected val bToR: TypeConverter[B, R]

  final def eval(left: A, right: B): R = evalImpl(aToR.convert(left), bToR.convert(right))

  protected def evalImpl(left: R, right: R): R
}


trait BinaryOpImplCompanionLowPriority[Ops[_, _, _]] {
  protected def build[A, B, R](numericR: Numeric[R], aToR: TypeConverter[A, R], bToR: TypeConverter[B, R]): Ops[A, B, R]

  implicit def castLeftToRight[L, R: Numeric](implicit tcl: TypeConverter[L, R]): Ops[L, R, R] = build(implicitly[Numeric[R]], tcl, TypeConverter.sameType)

  implicit def castRightToLeft[L: Numeric, R](implicit tcr: TypeConverter[R, L]): Ops[L, R, L] = build(implicitly[Numeric[L]], TypeConverter.sameType, tcr)

}

trait BinaryOpImplCompanion[Ops[_, _, _]] extends BinaryOpImplCompanionLowPriority[Ops] {
  implicit def sameType[T: Numeric]: Ops[T, T, T] = build(implicitly[Numeric[T]], TypeConverter.sameType, TypeConverter.sameType)
}

class SumImpl[A, B, R](val numericR: Numeric[R], val aToR: TypeConverter[A, R], val bToR: TypeConverter[B, R]) extends BinaryOpImpl[A, B, R] {
  override protected def evalImpl(left: R, right: R): R = numericR.plus(left, right)
}

object SumImpl extends BinaryOpImplCompanion[SumImpl] {
  override protected def build[A, B, R](numericR: Numeric[R], aToR: TypeConverter[A, R], bToR: TypeConverter[B, R]): SumImpl[A, B, R] = new SumImpl(numericR, aToR, bToR)
}

case class Sum[+T, L, R](left: Expression[L], right: Expression[R])(implicit impl: SumImpl[L, R, T]) extends Expression[T] {
  def eval = impl.eval(left.eval, right.eval)
}
```

usage example:

```
def test(): Unit = {
  println(Sum(Literal(3), Literal(1)).eval)
  println(Sum(Literal(1.1), Literal(1)).eval)
  println(Sum(Literal(1), Literal(1.1)).eval)
  println(Sum(Literal[Short](1), Literal(1.12)).eval) // composite conversion Short -> Int -> Double
}
```

Essentially the idea is to have one `implicit` variable that encapsulates all 3 relevant types instead of having 3 separate implicits. So the code complies if the compiler can build one composite evidence for a triplet LeftArgType-RightArgType-ResultType.

Comment: @user9457782, if I were you, I'd unaccepted this answer and waited some more (at least one day) for other solutions. This code looks too complicated to me but I was not able to come up with a simpler solution. Still someone else might be able to do so. Then come back and accept this answer if it is still the best one.

Answer (score 0):

the problem specifically is that `Sum(Literal(1.1), Literal(1))` has a `Literal[Double]` on the left and a `Literal[Int]` on the right. The LUB of `Int` and `Double` is indeed `AnyVal` as you have seen.

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/ALM9urR/1

works perfectly fine. I also think this is good behavior because adding different types can be a bit iffy but else you could introduce an implicit that lets you do the necessary conversions.

Comment: But I am using type bounds. Shouldn't the compiler figure out that it can convert the Int to a Double and then everything works as expected?

Comment: Just because the compiler will convert `Int` to `Double` doesn't mean that it will convert `F[Int]` to `F[Double]`. Doing so in general for any `F` wouldn't make sense, since the compiler knows nothing of the semantics of `F`.

Comment: In the example for Sum2 the issue is that `...plus(left.eval, right.eval)` expects two arguments of type `T`. But `left.eval` returns a `L` and `right.eval` a `R`. I specified, however, with the `<%` view bound that both `L` and `R` have to be convertible to `T`. So why does it not convert them?